# Related rates with snowball

Tags: calculus

The sun is shining and a spherical snowball of volume 340 ft$^3$ is melting at a rate of $10$ cubic feet per hour. As it melts, it remains spherical. At what rate is the radius changing after $2.5$ hours?

And this answer is wrong? please help
$10\times 2.5 =25$
$340 - 25 = 315$
so
$r^3 = \dfrac{315\times 3 }{ 4\pi}$
$r= 4.2$ ft

Comment: Your answer does not have any explanation. I would say the volume after 2.5 hours is ... so the radius at that point is ...  Note that line breaks disappear.  If you use two returns or put two spaces at the end of the line before the return you get the break you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by relating $\frac{dV}{dt}$ to $\frac{dr}{dt}$. As you know, the equation for spherical volume is given by
$$V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3.$$

If we treat $V$ and $r$ as both being implicitly differentiable functions of $t$, then differentiating implicitly across $V$ gives,
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}.$$

Solving this for $\frac{dr}{dt}$ we have,
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dt}\frac{1}{4\pi r^2}.$$

Now you were already given that $\frac{dV}{dt}=10$. All that is left is to find $r$ after $2.5$ hours. You have rightly concluded that in $2.5$ hours, $V=340-25=315$. To find $r$, try using your original formula for $V$ with this new volume for $V$. Solve that for $r$. Plug this new found value for $r$ into your equation for $\frac{dr}{dt}$, make sure the result makes sense, and have a nice day.

Comment: thanks, I get 10*(1/4pi(4.2)^2=138.54444 witch is wrong...

Comment: @Ozi:  Clearly $4 \pi (4.2)^2$ is greater than $1$, so you should get an answer rather less than $10$.  I suspect you multiplied instead of dividing.  Again, if you don't show your work, we can't find the error.

Comment: Try $$10\cdot\frac{1}{4\pi (4.2)^2}\approx 0.045$$ That is in feet per hour, so multiply by 12 to get inches. With increased precision by not cutting that number to $4.2$, I get $$\frac{10}{4 \pi  \sqrt[3]{\frac{315\cdot 3}{4 \pi }}^2}\approx 0.0446658$$ That is feet per hour, or about $0.54$ inches per hour. This is really close to the average rate of change over the interval, which bodes well for the result. In case you were wondering, this is initially a really big snowball($4.3 ft$ radius), it will take precisely 34 hours to melt.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have calculated the radius of a 315 ft^3 sphere correctly(though the precision is light).  You have not addressed how quickly it is decreasing, which is the question you have.  You need to take the derivative of the volume formula with respect to time to relate the decrease in volume to the decrease in radius

Comment: I still get wrong answers... could you please help solve this problem? thank you ROss

Comment: I can't diagnose your problem without seeing your work.  You are given dV/dt and asked for dr/dt.  Given that you know $r(V)$ this looks like a chain rule problem.

Comment: still confused, would you be kind to set proportion for me plesae?